# Conversion of data text into JSON data

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

How to convert by nifi processor

```json
{
  "values": [
    [
      "id",
      "type",
      "name",
      "mobile no"
    ],
    [
      "xyz",
      "detail",
      "bob",
      "5283992123"
    ],
    [
      "pqr",
      "seconDEtail",
      "bob2",
      "6746789887"
    ]
  ]
}
```

into

```json
[
  {
    "id": "xyz",
    "type": "detail",
    "name": "bob",
    "mobile no ": "5283992123"
  },
  {
    "id": "pqr",
    "type": "seconDEtail",
    "name": "bob2",
    "mobile no ": "6746789887"
  }
]
```

How to do this conversion by nifi processor in efficient way. The data is dynamic provided by some remote location

Comment: text data is comma separated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired output by running two shifts:

1. Creating temporary object, and grouping the keys and values by position in the array.
2. Then iterating over that object values to create the outputs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        // first element in array
        "0": {
          // for all items in array
          "*": {
            // set value as n.key
            "@": "&.key"
          }
        },
        // for everything else in the array
        "*": {
          // for all items in array
          "*": {
            // set values as n.value[]
            "@": "&.values"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // for all items in our temp object
      "*": {
        "values": {
          // for each values
          "*": {
            // set value with key in our temp object and use index as array position
            "@": "[&1].@(3,key)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And to change values of a specific key:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        // first element in array
        "0": {
          // for all items in array
          "*": {
            // match id
            "id": {
              // override value
              "#transaction_id": "&2.key"
            },
            // for everything else
            "*": {
              // set value as n.key
              "@1": "&2.key"
            }
          }
        },
        // for everything else in the array
        "*": {
          // for all items in array
          "*": {
            // set values as n.value[]
            "@": "&.values"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // for all items in our temp object
      "*": {
        "values": {
          // for each values
          "*": {
            // set value with key in our temp object and use index as array position
            "@": "[&1].@(3,key)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can we change some attribute like "id" into "transaction_id"

Comment: I've added another transform that would allow you to change keys.